# Some properties of a finite group with all Sylow subgroups that are cyclic

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

I consider a finite group $G$ such that all its Sylow's subgroups are cyclic. 
I suppose  that  $|G|=p_1^{k_1}...p_n^{k_n}$ with $p_1<...<p_n$ distinct primes.

Can I say something about the normality of the $p_i$-Sylow subgroups? Can I say for instance that $P_n$ is normal?

I know then that if $P_1$ is a $p_1$- Sylow subgroup than  $G$ has a $p_1$ normal complement K.

Is it true that $K$ is cyclic? How can I show that?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: No, $K$ need not be cyclic (this is easy to check by considering some examples). The Sylow-$p_n$ subgroup will be normal by induction, and the group will be an iterated semidirect product of the Sylows in descending order.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thank you! I don't understand very well how can I prove the normality of $P_n$ by induction

Comment: You need to use (or at least this makes it a lot easier) that normal Hall subgroups are characteristic, so you can use transitivity.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Ah ok..thank you so much for the help!

Comment: By the way, these groups are sometimes call $Z$-groups, though I am unsure how common the term is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the remarks of Tobias (with $G=S_3$ you can refute your statement), one can prove that if a group has cyclic Sylow subgroups, it must be *solvable* (of derived length $\leq 2$). For a proof see for example M.I. Isaacs, [Finite Group Theory](http://mathhome.ir/my_doc/mathhome/Ketabkhane/Books/English%20Resources/l7/New%20Folder%20%283%29/__Finite_Group_Theory__Graduate_Studies_in_Mathematics__copy%28isaacs%29.pdf), Corollary 5.15

Comment: $S_3$ does not refute the normal complement being cyclic. The group is even supersolvable (though this is rarely as relevant), and thus an $M$-group (and also an IPR-group though probably nobody but I care about those).

Comment: That is true, but I was referring to the normality of all Sylow subgroups. Yes true that it is supersolvable and hence monomial, but I doubt if Gloria has come across the definitions of these kind of groups.

Comment: Ahh, I don't seem to see any claims of them all being normal, just a question about what can be said about their normality and whether the $p_n$ one is normal.

Comment: Ah right, I read $G$ being cyclic, where it says $K$.